# BootStrap.groovy content doesn't update the content

Tags: grails, bootstrapping

I'm new to Grails and study it via InfoQ's "Getting Started With Grails" book.
Running through it I've faced a problem with the BootStrap.groovy file:

1. I've edited it as the book says.
2. Run-app it - and the data I've entered into BootStrap.groovy has been shown.
3. I've updated the bootstrapping values but they are not changed.
   No errors are shown in the console.

What I've tried:

- exchanging def's places;
- set Runner's class value to nullables;
- changed .save(failOnError:true) to .save(flush:true).

Even after I've changed the Race class' bootstrapping values it looks like it hasn't been changed.

Looks like the value is taken from somewhere else than the BootStrap.groovy?

I use Grails 2.2.1 with a PostgreSQL DB.
The classes' code is below:

```
package racetrack

class Runner {
    static constraints = {
        firstName(blank:false)
        lastName(blank:false)
        dateOfBirth(nullable:true)
        gender(inList:["M","F"])
        address(nullable:true)
        city(nullable:true)
        state(nullable:true)
        zipcode(nullable:true)
        email(email:true)
    }

    static hasMany = [registrations:Registration]

    /*static mapping = {
        sort "email"
    }*/

    String firstName
    String lastName
    Date dateOfBirth
    String gender
    String address
    String city
    String state
    String zipcode
    String email

    String toString(){
        "${firstName} ${lastName} (${email})"
    }
}
```

and

```
package racetrack

class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
        def begun = new Runner(firstName:"Marathon",
            lastName:"Runner",
            dateOfBirth:"",
            gender:"M",
            address:"",
        city:"",
            state:"",
            zipcode:"",
            email:"me@me.ru"
            )
        begun.save(flush:true)

        def zabeg = new Race(name:"Run SPB",
            startDate:new Date() + 360*30,
            city:"Moscow",
            state:"Moscow",
            cost:10.0,
            distance:42.0,
            maxRunners:10)
        zabeg.save(flush:true)
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

EDIT: could this be happening due to any `generate-*` scripts been run?

Race.groovy:

```
package racetrack

class Race {
    static hasMany = [registrations:Registration]

    String name
    Date startDate
    String city
    String state
    BigDecimal distance
    BigDecimal cost
    Integer maxRunners

    static constraints = {
        name(blank:false, maxSize:50)
        startDate(validator: {
                return (it >= new Date())
            }
        )
        city()
        state(inList:["Moscow", "Volgograd", "SPb", "NN"])
        distance(min:0.0)
        cost(min:0.0, max:100.0)
        maxRunners(min:0, max:100000)
    }

    static mapping = {
        sort "startDate"
    }

    BigDecimal inMiles(){
        return distance*0.6214
    }

    String toString(){
        return "${name}, ${startDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy')}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything seems fine, what problem you are getting.??

Answer (score 0):

`BootStrap` should be in `grails-app/conf` instead. Refer [this](http://grails.org/Bootstrap+Classes).

Comment: How does Race.groovy look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the errors of the new instance you save by adding

```
print begun.errors
```

See if somethings comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove

```
def index() { }
```

from the controllers.

I had the same issue. Now it is fixed.